# Facebook share not working in subdirectory wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, share

i have two wordpress sites, one in root and another in a subdirectory, named fr.

For the wordpress in the root directory the facebook share is working fine, but in case of subdirectory its not working.

here is my links

https://www.acanac.com/blog/general-category/your-go-to-halloween-safety-and-party-blog/ - Working fine

https://www.acanac.com/fr/blog/general-category/votre-blogue-de-reference-sur-la-securite-et-les-fetes-a-lhalloween/ -  Not working

This is the code i am using in my site.

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php the_title() ?>&amp;p[url]=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;p[images][0]=','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)" class="" title="" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook icon"></i></a>
```

Can any one please help me..... Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you post your code, mean how you want to share this link

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Hasibur Rahaman,  i am using Yoast SEO plugin for sharing.

Comment: @ WizKid, In case of french url facebook share the Image,title,descriptions are not taking from the french site.